# Stubbing XHR2 during tests

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, sinon

Usually we go with [Sinon](https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS) when trying to stub/fake XHR. But recently we run into a bunch of problems with it when trying to fake XHR2.

It would seem that Sinon is not fully compatible with XHR2 implementation yet. A notable issue is empty `xhr.response` (not to be confused with `xhr.responseText`). This makes testing XHR2 response much more difficult.

Is there a better alternative out there for XHR2 testing? What's a good starting point for mocking/stubbing XHR2?

Comment: look like it covers xhr.response: https://github.com/cjohansen/Sinon.JS/blob/master/lib/sinon/util/fake_xml_http_request.js#L214

Comment: @dandavis I would love to be proven wrong, but in my test, Sinon returns xhr.response as undefined while xhr.responseText contains the correct string (even when responseType is `text` or ``). see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Properties

Comment: @dandavis after looking at it for a longer time, i realize this is a bug on sinon's end, `xhr.response` is not ready at LOADING state, you need to wait until DONE state to get `response`.

Comment: ok, the problem is not the response property, its that xhr.responseType is never set in the mock open(). you could likely say xhrOb.responseType='blob'; and it will tunnel into the real request.

Comment: @dandavis responseType defaults to `''`, ie. string; so `response` should at least be the same as `responseText` even if no responseType is set.

Comment: there's no real need to use .response unless a custom responseType is set, but if it's off from the spec it should probably be filed or forked...